# Sun Access Manager

Tags: single-sign-on

i'm looking to learn about SSO, and heard about Sun Access Manager and openSSO(?)
I want to build a small system that does SSO, like have Apache as a front end working with an SSO server.
Should I investigate Sun AM and is openSSO a product?
Do they offer these free for developers?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenSSO is the new name for Sun Access Manager. OpenSSO is open source; source code and binaries are freely available from http://opensso.org/. OpenSSO **Express** builds are released every three months; OpenSSO **Enterprise** 8.0 is the next commercial product release after Sun Access Manager 7.1, due November 14th.

You can use OpenSSO for free, or buy license/support and deploy either the Express or Enterprise version - your choice. It's a growing, vibrant community, with [many deployments](http://blogs.oracle.com/superpat/tags/adoption).